# "App" has stopped android studio debuging

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to RUN on device 7.0 andorid get error *App has stopped*

This is Logcat:

```
      09-08 16:20:39.510 24313-24313/? E/Zygote: v2
  09-08 16:20:39.511 24313-24313/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
  09-08 16:20:39.819 24313-24313/com.test.myacc.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.test.myacc.test, PID: 24313
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.myacc.test/com.test.myacc.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
          at com.test.myacc.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

In debuging has no errors, all files is clean

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.myacc.test">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".HelpActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>
</application>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.test.myacc.test

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.TextView


class MainActivity : Activity() {

private var timer: CountDownTimer? = null
lateinit var tvCompany: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

   menuActivity()

    tvCompany = findViewById(R.id.tvCompany) as TextView

    val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.screensaver_company)
    tvCompany.startAnimation(anim)

    timer = object : CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

        override fun onFinish() {
            tvCompany.text = "PRESENTS"
        }
    }.start()

    timer = object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

        override fun onFinish() {
            tvCompany.text = "GAME"
        }
    }.start()

    timer = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

        override fun onFinish() {
            menuActivity()
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun menuActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    val id = item.itemId


    return if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        true
    } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
 }
```

I read all thread on S.O but no one helped to fix my problem..

Btw the code is converted from java file to kotlin file and all errors are fixed... application crashed when i try to run test.

Comment: savedInstanceState can be null so you should declare it as a nullable type: *onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)* (notice the ? appended to Bundle).

Comment: Same `?` no change nothing

Comment: Any other errors when you added `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` ? I mean, perhaps trying to use `AppCompatActivity()` instead of `Activity()` or sth?